# Sitecore Lucene index - exclude items by template

Tags: indexing, lucene, sitecore

I have created a custom index and I want to exclude some items that are created from a known template. I setup this in the config but doesn't seem to work:

```
          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
            <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
              <templateId>{C4770867-35D0-4B09-8A02-9EC9CFBB60BA}</templateId>
            </exclude >               
          </documentOptions>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give some more information? What is not working exactly? Maybe share some more of your config..  How did you verify?

Comment: Dora can you also compare your index with a default Sitecore 8.1 index configuration? Maybe you are missing some other definition. It's also handy to use a debug tool like Luke

Comment: How did you find it doesn't work ? Did you try with Luke ?

Comment: did you rebuilt your index after setting this?.

Answer (score 3):

Depends which Sitecore version you are using. In Sitecore 8.1 the `list:ExcludeTemplate` was replaced by `list:AddExcludedTemplate`

http://www.sitecorecoffee.com/2016/01/sitecore-81-creating-custom-search-index.html

Comment: yes, I'm using Sitecore 8.1 and the method used is list:AddExcludedTemplate, but it doesn't work